# How to remove macOS Console devices connected over the network

Tags: xcode, macos, console, console-application, macos-mojave

I use console to track device logs. At work I've connected many co-workers phones to Xcode and have since removed them from the Device and Simulators window. However, those devices are still appearing in Console and when I select them I am able to see their logs.

How can I remove these devices?